# Handling Java crypto exceptions

Tags: java, security, exception, encryption, cryptography

This, pretty basic, piece of code is quite common when handling encryption / decryption in Java.

```
final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, iv);
cipher.doFinal(*something*);
```

These three lines alone, potentially throw six exceptions and I'm not sure what's the cleanest (in terms of code readability) way to handle them.
A try with six catch clauses really looks like a smell to me.

Are there micropatterns or best practices, I am obviously missing, when working with such objects?

**EDIT**

Sorry, I think I didn't explain myself very well. My question is not really about avoiding a try\catch clause, but if there is a common way to handle similar situations.

The cryptographic exceptions are

```
NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException
InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, InvalidKeyException,
BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException
```

Comment: A try with six catch clauses might be a code smell, but it may not be incorrect either. What six exceptions can be thrown from this block of code? Would each one indicate that a different issue occurred?

Comment: One un-differentiated catch is absolutely a smell. Good question +1

Comment: Four or five of these six are programming errors and for that reason should be caught separately. Now that we can | exceptions together the question is obsolete.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You indicated the following exceptions:

```
NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException
InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, InvalidKeyException,
BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException
```

Now all of these are [`GeneralSecurityException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/GeneralSecurityException.html)'s, so it would be easy to catch them all. But looking at the use case, you probably don't want to do that.

---

If you look at the cause of the exceptions then you will find that any of these exceptions - except for the last two - are only thrown when generating an implementation of an algorithm or a key. I think it is reasonable that once you have tested your application that these values remain more or less static. Hence it would be logical to throw - for instance - an [`IllegalStateException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalStateException.html). `IllegalStateException` is a runtime exception which you are not required to throw (in the method signature) or catch. Of course, you should include the security exception as being the *cause* of the exception.

---

Now the last two exceptions, [`BadPaddingException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/crypto/BadPaddingException.html) and [`IllegalBlockSizeException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/crypto/IllegalBlockSizeException.html) are different. They depend on the actual ciphertext, so they are dependent on the input of the algorithm. Now normally you should always verify the integrity of the input before you feed it into your [`Cipher`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html) instance, initiated for decryption, for instance by first validating a HMAC checksum). So in that sense you could still get away with a runtime exception. If you don't perform a separate check for integrity then you should do should not convert to a `RuntimeException`. Instead you could either let the user handle the exception, or re-throw it as a use case specific exception.

If you handle the `BadPaddingException` by (re-)throwing it then should understand about plaintext oracle attacks such as padding oracle attacks. For padding oracle attacks in CBC mode: if an adversary can try and let you decrypt ciphertext multiple times and receive an indication that decryption failed (or not) then they can *retrieve the plaintext of the message without breaking the cipher*. For this reason an authenticated mode such as GCM mode should be preferred in situations that can handle the 16 additional bytes for the authentication tag.

---

It is probably best to use separate `try`/`catch` blocks for the construction and initialization of the `Cipher` and the decryption itself. You could also catch the exceptions `BadPaddingException` and `IllegalBlockSizeException` before handling the [`GeneralSecurityException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/GeneralSecurityException.html). Starting with Java 7 you may use multi-catch statements as well (e.g. `catch(final BadPaddingException | IllegalBlockSizeException e)`).

---

Finally some notes:

- [`BadPaddingException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/crypto/BadPaddingException.html) and [`IllegalBlockSizeException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/crypto/IllegalBlockSizeException.html) may be thrown by `Cipher` because the data was not completely received, but it may also be because of an attacker messing with the data;
- [`BadPaddingException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/crypto/BadPaddingException.html) may also be thrown if the key is incorrect.
- Beware that an exception may be thrown for AES key sizes 192 bit and 256 bit if the unlimited crypto files are not being installed (check the [Oracle JavaSE site](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) for more info); you should check if the key size is permitted when the application is started (this is mainly true for old / deprecated versions of Java). Newer versions of Java do not require these unlimited crypto files.

Answer (score 3):

If you are willing to lose some specificty, all of the Crypto exceptions extend [GeneralSecurityException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/security/GeneralSecurityException.html), you can just catch that instead.

Answer (score -3):

The best way to handle that is to create a bussines exception (MyModuleException or something) and then rethrow that exception adding Crypto exceptions to cause part. In that way your method would throw only one exception, not six, what would be much easier to manage in other layers of your application.

```
public void myMethod(...) throws MyModuleException {
  try {
    final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, iv);
    cipher.doFinal(*something*);
  } catch(Crypto1Ex ex){
    throw new MyModuleException("something is wrong", ex); //ex added, so it is not lost and visible in stacktraceses
  } catch(Crypto1Ex ex){
    throw new MyModuleException("something is wrong", ex);
  } //etc.
}
```

In Java 7 you might handle it even easier (see: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/catch-multiple.html)

Comment: This is more or less what I'm doing at the moment. Unfortunately I can't use Java7 features or that would be the way I would take.