# Key user not authenticated when using a SecretKey directly as loaded from keystore

Tags: android, encryption, keystore

I'm trying to encrypt data use Cipher with SecretKey loaded in KeyStore but always got this error :

> **Caused by: android.security.KeyStoreException: Key user not authenticated**

I tried creating SecretKeySpec myself it worked. I'm using android Q to test.

Can anyone help me explain the problem?

My code

```
    public Cipher createCipher() {
        Cipher cipher;
        try {
            cipher = Cipher.getInstance(
                    KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES + "/"
                            + KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_CBC + "/"
                            + KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_PKCS7);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to get Cipher", e);
        }
        return cipher;
    }

    public boolean initCipher() {
        try {
            cipher = createCipher();
            SecretKey key = KeyStoreTools.getSecretKey(KEY_NAME);
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
            return true;
        } catch (KeyPermanentlyInvalidatedException e) {
            KeyStoreTools.removeAlias(KEY_NAME);
            return false;
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to init Cipher", e);
        }
    }
    public static SecretKey getSecretKey(String keyName) {
        Key key = getKey(keyName);
        if (!keyExists(key)) {
            key = generateKey(keyName);
        }
        return (SecretKey) key;
    }

    public static SecretKey generateKey(String keyName) {
        SecretKey secretKey = null;
        try {
            KeyGenerator keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES, ANDROID_KEY_STORE);
            KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder builder = new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(keyName,
                    KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT | KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT);
            builder.setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_CBC)
                    .setUserAuthenticationRequired(true)
                    .setEncryptionPaddings(
                            KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_PKCS7);
            keyGenerator.init(builder.build());
            secretKey = keyGenerator.generateKey();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchProviderException exc) {
            exc.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to generateKey", e);
        }
        return secretKey;
    }

    public String encrypt(Cipher cipher, byte[] dataToEncrypt) {
        try {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
            md.update(dataToEncrypt);
            byte[] enc = cipher.doFinal(md.digest());
            String base64 = Base64.encodeToString(enc, Base64.DEFAULT);
            return base64;
        } catch (BadPaddingException | IllegalBlockSizeException | NoSuchAlgorithmException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "";
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My issue throw because :

I encrypt using the cipher before the key has been flagged for successful user authentication. So move encrypt in onAuthenticationSucceeded and it's worked.

Hope my answer will help someone else.