# AES Encryption Decryption takes longer time

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography

I am using below code for encryption & decryption in Spring boot project with conveter annotation on attributes which I want to encrypt & decrypt

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

import javax.crypto.*;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import javax.persistence.AttributeConverter;
import javax.persistence.Converter;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.security.*;
import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;
import java.security.spec.InvalidParameterSpecException;

@Converter
public class CryptoConverter implements AttributeConverter<String, String> {

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(String attribute) {
        if(attribute == null){
            return null;
        }
        try {
        byte[] ivBytes;
        //String password="Hello";
        String password = EncryptionUtil.key.get();
        SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
        byte bytes[] = new byte[20];
        random.nextBytes(bytes);
        byte[] saltBytes = bytes;
// Derive the key
        SecretKeyFactory factory = null;

            factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");

        PBEKeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(),saltBytes,65556,256);
        SecretKey secretKey = factory.generateSecret(spec);
        SecretKeySpec secret = new SecretKeySpec(secretKey.getEncoded(), "AES");

            //encrypting the word
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secret);
            AlgorithmParameters params = cipher.getParameters();
            ivBytes =   params.getParameterSpec(IvParameterSpec.class).getIV();
            byte[] encryptedTextBytes =  cipher.doFinal(attribute.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            //prepend salt and vi
            byte[] buffer = new byte[saltBytes.length + ivBytes.length + encryptedTextBytes.length];
            System.arraycopy(saltBytes, 0, buffer, 0, saltBytes.length);
            System.arraycopy(ivBytes, 0, buffer, saltBytes.length, ivBytes.length);
            System.arraycopy(encryptedTextBytes, 0, buffer, saltBytes.length + ivBytes.length, encryptedTextBytes.length);
            return new Base64().encodeToString(buffer);

        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvalidParameterSpecException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData) {

        if(dbData == null){
            return null;
        }

        try {
            String password = EncryptionUtil.key.get();
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        //strip off the salt and iv
        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(new Base64().decode(dbData));
        byte[] saltBytes = new byte[20];
        buffer.get(saltBytes, 0, saltBytes.length);
        byte[] ivBytes1 = new byte[cipher.getBlockSize()];
        buffer.get(ivBytes1, 0, ivBytes1.length);
        byte[] encryptedTextBytes = new byte[buffer.capacity() - saltBytes.length - ivBytes1.length];

        buffer.get(encryptedTextBytes);
        // Deriving the key
        SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
        PBEKeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(), saltBytes, 65556, 256);
        SecretKey secretKey = factory.generateSecret(spec);
        SecretKeySpec secret = new SecretKeySpec(secretKey.getEncoded(), "AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secret, new IvParameterSpec(ivBytes1));
        byte[] decryptedTextBytes = null;

            decryptedTextBytes = cipher.doFinal(encryptedTextBytes);


        return new String(decryptedTextBytes);

        } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

The issue is this code takes a lot of time to encrypt & decrypt.

With this I am getting a serious performance hit.

Comment: have you profiled the code to see where it is spending all the time?

Comment: The code was perhaps copy&pasted from somewhere and you have no idea what it does or why? You say it takes a longer time, but longer than *what*? You do have a PBE scheme which uses iterations to slow the work of an attacker, but it also makes your code work harder. That's by design.

Comment: I see you have some trouble handling your exceptions, try reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15712409/589259); don't forget to upvote if it is useful to you. The general use of cryptographic primitives is OK, although you may want to use AES/GCM/NoPadding instead of CBC mode if you want to have more security.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to encrypt faster than simply use an actual randomly generated key instead of a password. You can store that in a `KeyStore` instance that you protect with a password if you like.

You could also simply move the PBKDF2 key derivation out of the encryption method itself and store the resulting `SecretKey` instance in a field *if and only if* the password doesn't change in between calls. That way you only have to derive the key once.

PBKDF2 currently uses 65556 iterations *each time* you want to encrypt/decrypt anything. And PBKDF2 consists of a single hash - in this case SHA-1 - taking 64 bytes at a time. So even before you start encrypting you've hashed at least 65556 (or 64Ki + 20 for some reason) times 64 bytes. That's 4 MiB of hashing you're doing before starting to encrypt. Compared to that you won't even notice the AES encryption.